# Is this in linear time and constant space? (sort array, so that all 0s are at the end, other numbers are at front (solution))

Tags: c++

The problem: You are given an array of a bunch of numbers and zeros, sort it so that all the numbers that are **not zero**, are at the **front**, and all the numbers at the **end** are **zeros**.

**Question:** Does my solution run in *Linear time* ? Or not ? Also is it *constant space* or not?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cin.tie(0);
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    vector<int> MyVec;
    int input;
    int i = 0;
    stack<int> mystack;
    stack<int> zerostack;
    while((input = getchar())&& (input!=10))
    {
        if(input != 32)
        {
            MyVec.push_back(input - '0');

            if(MyVec[i] == 0)
                zerostack.push(MyVec[i]);
            else
                mystack.push(MyVec[i]);

            i++;
        }
    }
    MyVec.clear();
    while(!mystack.empty())
    {
         MyVec.push_back(mystack.top());
         mystack.pop();
    }
    while(!zerostack.empty())
    {
         MyVec.push_back(zerostack.top());
         zerostack.pop();
    }
    for(auto a : MyVec)
        cout << a << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can roughly test that something runs in linear time by continuously increasing the number of elements and seeing whether the runtime increases accordingly at large values of N. It might not be perfect, but it's a starting point when you're unsure about the theoretical analysis.

Comment: You have every number twice, once in `MyVec` and once in one of the `stack`s, so you used up O(N) additional space.

Comment: oh right, so I can just remove the " MyVec.push_back(input - '0');" line, and insert the input-'0' directly into the stacks , right?

Comment: With queues you could eliminate MyVec completely. But as "you are given an array" you would be solving a slightly different problem.

Comment: @MassSpectrometer A bit offtopic - can you please undelete your deleted question with [BBAD Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72278467/)? I was writing a huge and efficient solution and post for it, while you deleted Question at this time. I created a [Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244931/) for us two, please answer me there, I also posted some messages there about timings of my solution.

Answer (score 2):

##### Answer to your question

- Your solution **does not** consume a constant amount of space.
  You store each element you read into `MyVec` and `mystack` or `zerostack`.
  So it'll be `O(n)` in terms of space consumed.
- Your solution **does** run in linear time (`O(n)`), but it's not a single-pass algorithm.
  All your loops will loop `N` times or less, there are no nested loops, so it'll run in `O(n)` time.
  However you can still reduce the real runtime of the program by using a better algorithm.

---

##### Potential solutions

It's not very clear to me if you need to optimize the entire program or only the part where you sort the vector, so i'll add solutions for both.

###### Whole Program

If the whole program is to be optimized you can take advantage of the fact that only the zeroes need to be shifted to the back.

So if it's not a zero you can directly output it and if it's a zero you just need to remember to output it later after all input has been processed.

e.g.:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int zeroes = 0;
    char c;
    while((std::cin >> c) && c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        if(c == '0')
          zeroes++;
        else
          std::cout << c << " ";
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < zeroes; i++)
        std::cout << "0 ";

    return 0;
}
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/v8Gd3PhWb)

This will run in linear time (`O(n)`) and consume a constant amount of space.

###### Just the sorting of the array

in case you just need to write a function that sorts a vector, you can apply a similar technique by swapping any zeroes you encounter to the end of the vector.

This will however not preserve the order of the elements (it's an unstable sorting algorithm).

```cpp
void sortVector(std::vector<int>& values) {
    int insertPosition = values.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < insertPosition; i++) {
        while(values[i] == 0 && i < insertPosition)
            std::swap(values[i], values[--insertPosition]);
    }
}
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/rj3GfaKd4)

This will also run in linear time (`O(n)`) and consumes a constant amount of space (we aren't allocating anything, just shifting stuff around)

It's linear time because each iteration of the while loop decrements the number of times the for loop needs to loop.

if it actually needs to be a stable sort, then you could accomplish it in a similar fashion like the whole program answer - you keep track of the zeroes and write out the numbers, e.g.:

```cpp
void sortVector(std::vector<int>& values) {
    int zeroes = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        if(values[i] == 0)
            zeroes++;
        else {
            values[i-zeroes] = values[i];
            if(zeroes > 0) values[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/he89dhsEj)

This has the same time-complexity and space-complexity, but sorts them in a stable way.

Comment: Just delete the part where you said O(2n).  I'm campaigning to help eliminate such things.  The whole point is to remove the constant in front of n so don't put it back in, not for a second, not even to immediately follow it up with "or just O(n)" just don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Not optimized both in time and space complexity.
You used extra vector to store and print the elements. You can print those elements without help of vector.

Better you can solve it with **deque** in C++ STL.

Comment: Good idea. Also, as two passes using `std::vector` And `std::partition` or `std::stable_partition` would be good too and I bet would outperform `std::deque`.

Comment: @Ben [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) would not be constant space though (it allocates a dynamic buffer which could be very large). If it chooses the allocation-less algorithm it would be `O(nlog(n))` in time complexity. `std::partition` would work though and be quite efficient at it :)